# Publish-AzureServiceProject command failed for node.js application

Tags: node.js, azure

I am following this tutorial to deploy node.js application from my machine to windows azure:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/

my command is as below:

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName socketlistener -Location "East US" -Launch
```

but I am getting the following error

```
Publishing  to Windows Azure. This may take several minutes...

1:32:36 PM - Preparing runtime deployment for service 'socketlistener'
1:32:38 PM - Preparing deployment for socketlistener with Subscription ID: ***...
1:32:40 PM - Verifying storage account 'socketlistener'...

Publish-AzureService : Path for package doesn't exist in D:\dev\node\socketlistener\cloud_package.cspkg.
At line:1 char:21
Publish-AzureService <<<<
CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Publish-AzureService], FileNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am suspecting is that there is some issue with your application configuration (Service Definition or Service Configuration) which is causing problem in  package  creation. The error message also suggests the same problem. Based on Publish-AzureServiceProject command execution the next step is to create the package after verifying the storage account. And after the package creation, the next step is to connect service endpoint which you can verify in the same link above you are following in tutorial.

To verify that there is no issue with your machine or connection to Windows Azure application, try creating a new Node.js application, add new web/worker role and do not make any changes in configuration then try deploying. This will verify if there is any issue with your machine configuration (if any) or other issue:

- New-AzureServiceProject your_node_project
- Add-AzureNodeWebRole
- Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName socketlistener -Location "East US" -Launch

Comment: May I ask if there is a way to get verbose details when launching commands?