# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I try to deploy my Azure Cloud Service via CLI

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm running this command in the Azure PowerShell to deploy my node project:

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName <name> -Location "East US"
```

Using my service name instead of `<name>`.

Each time I run this, I get an error:

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject : Object reference not set to an instance of an
object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName <name> -Location "East US"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Publish-AzureServiceProject], N
   ullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.CloudService.Pub
   lishAzureServiceProjectCommand
```

Can anyone help? I've found similar questions here referencing deployment from Visual Studio, but I don't know how to (or if I can or should) take the steps advised for those problems since I'm building a node project from the command line.

**UPDATE:** Confirmed that I have added my certificate. This is apparently part of the publish profile import. I have also tried the manual authentication method, but neither seems to work. I'm still getting exactly the same error.

**UPDATE 2:** The command fails with the same error if I run `Publish-AzureServiceProject` while in this directory even without any parameters. This leads me to believe incorrect parameter values are not the issue.

I now believe the issue is with my ServiceDefinition.csdef although I'm not sure. I started a new Node app just to test publishing. I was able to start publishing and get further than I'm getting with this app even without creating the new service in Azure.

Here's my ServiceDefinition.csdef. I've removed the service name in case that could be a security risk.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="<name>" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WorkerRole name="CoreServer" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="setup_worker.cmd &gt; log.txt" executionContext="elevated">
        <Environment>
          <Variable name="EMULATED">
            <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
          </Variable>
          <Variable name="RUNTIMEID" value="node" />
          <Variable name="RUNTIMEURL" value="http://az413943.vo.msecnd.net/node/0.8.4.exe" />
        </Environment>
      </Task>
      <Task commandLine="node.cmd .\startup.js" executionContext="elevated" />
    </Startup>
    <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="AGS_Working_Directory" sizeInMB="1024" />
    </LocalResources>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="tcp" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Runtime>
      <Environment>
        <Variable name="PORT">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/Endpoints/Endpoint[@name='HttpIn']/@port" />
        </Variable>
        <Variable name="EMULATED">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
        </Variable>
      </Environment>
      <EntryPoint>
        <ProgramEntryPoint commandLine="node.cmd .\server.js" setReadyOnProcessStart="true" />
      </EntryPoint>
    </Runtime>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

DeployTesting.ps1 script:

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
Set-Location $ScriptDir

Copy-Item $ScriptDir\CoreServer\node_modules\dbResources.js.test -Destination $scriptDir\CoreServer\node_modules\dbResources.js

Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName <name> -Location "East US" -Slot staging
```

Issue posted on Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/2463

Comment: have you set up azure powershell with your certificate?

Comment: @paqogomez I'm not entirely sure. I've grabbed my publish profile and imported that. Does that take care of the certificate?

Comment: You have to do every step [listed here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/), dont skip any.

Comment: @paqogomez I have followed all the steps there. I've even tried both methods for authenticating although the text reads as though one or the other will suffice. Still getting the error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do any of the powershell commands work?

Comment: @paqogomez Yes, other commands work. I was able to import the publish profile. `Get-AzureSubscription` shows a certificate valid until 4/22/15. Are those the sorts of commands you mean?

Comment: Yes, the only other thing i have is to suggest that either your `<name>` doesnt exist or is malformed, or `"East US"` is not in the correct format.

Comment: Check this also http://stackoverflow.com/a/14049410/2589202

Comment: Can you show the full sequence of commands you are running (i.e. are you calling Set-AzureServiceProject, then Publish-AzureServiceProject)?

Comment: @viperguynaz I just added my testing deployment script to the bottom. It's really simple, and, no, it doesn't use Set-AzureServiceProject. The script was based on my client's existing deployment process which did not include that cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of PowerShell are you using?

My guess is that one of the files that makes up the service is missing from the place powersahell expects it. The newer versions of PowerShell require the following files in the service directory:

(1) ServiceDefinition.csdef
(2) ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg
(3) ServiceConfguration.Local.cscfg
(4) A directory with your role files, with name matching the role name

Older versions also require

deploymentSettings.json

Please file a bug as Ogail suggests and include your service directory details

Or github url has changed, it is now

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues

Comment: I'm running version 3 of PowerShell.

Comment: Issue posted. Thank you for the help. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/2463

Answer (score 1):

Could you please file an issue on https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/ and attach your service project folder? This will help in debugging the problem.

Thanks,
Elogeel

Comment: Issue posted. I couldn't attach my folder because it exceeded the max size, but I posted a link to a Google Drive share of the zipped folder. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/2463